# Changing Plugin Action Icon from code

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins, intellij-idea

I am developing a plugin for Android Studio (Intellij Idea). I want to change the icon when an action is being performed.

But its not changing the icon.

Here is the code -

```
public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent event) {

        Project project = event.getData(PlatformDataKeys.PROJECT);

        ActionManager actionManager = event.getActionManager();
        AnAction anAction = actionManager.getAction("York.toggle");
        Presentation presentation = anAction.getTemplatePresentation();
        presentation.setIcon(IconLoader.getIcon("/icons/ic_fav_search_24dp.png"));


        /*String adbPath = getAdpPathOnMachine(project);
        BroadcastHelper.main(new String[]{adbPath});*/
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnActionEvent#getPresentation`

Comment: Thanks, I was making mistake as I was using the anAction.getTemplatePresentation(); instead of anAction.getPresentation();

Comment: that method does not exist in that class

Comment: The code of the OP is actually correct and is working for me

Comment: Depends if you are adding an action to a new place or updating existing one. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/basic-action-system.html